# Write an expression whose value is true if and only if x is NOT a letter

Tags: python

Assume that `x` is a string variable that has been given a value. Write an expression whose value is `true` if and only if `x` is NOT a letter.

Comment: what does your attempt look like?

Comment: I tried notx.true() recently and it says Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: notx, true

More Hints:
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: not
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: x

Comment: `x != 'a'` tests if `x` is not a. `x != 'a' and x != 'b'` tests if it is neither 'a' nor 'b' ... This should be your first attempt. Then you learn about the `in` operator and/or comparisons. Then you might deviate from the right path and learn regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

```
def isLetter(ch):
    import string
    return len(ch) == 1 and ch in string.ascii_letters


print(isLetter('A'))
True
```

Comment: *Write an expression whose value is true if and only if x is NOT a letter*, this is the most roundabout way possible to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the type of the variable `x`, you can use the following:

```
if type(x) is str:
    print 'is a string'
```

In python, String and Char will have the same type and same output unlike languages like java.

```
type(chr(65)) == str
type('A') == str
```

**EDIT:**

As @Kay suggested, you should use `isinstance(foo, Bar)` instead of `type(foo) is bar` since isinstance is checking for inheritance while type does not.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) for more details about `isinstance` vs `type`

Using isinstance will also support unicode strings.

```
isinstance(u"A", basestring)
>>> true

# Here is an example of why isinstance is better than type
type(u"A") is str
>>> false
type(u"A") is basestring
>>> false
type(u"A") is unicode
>>> true
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using regex to validate ONLY ONE letter

```
import re

re.match("^[a-zA-Z]$", "a") is not None
>>> True

re.match("^[a-zA-Z]$", "0") is not None
>>> False
```

Comment: Don't do `type(foo) is Bar`. Use `isinstance(foo, Bar)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer to it is `not((x>='A' and x<='Z') or (x>='a' and x<='z'))`

Comment: Actually Python allows you to write comparisons like a mathematical notation: `a < b < c` <-> `a < b and b < c`, but `a`, `b` and `c` are only evaluated once.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that. I will have to try it out

Comment: No need to overly complicate it `return not x.isalpha()`, it if it is not alphabetic it cannot be a letter

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression. http://www.pythex.org is a good learning spot, official docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

something like this should work though:

`if x != '[a-zA-Z]':`

Comment: This is not Perl. Also digit != letter.